I have created a SharePoint library but my colleague can not upload a file
I have created a SharePoint library but my colleague can not upload a file.
Why is that? And how to solve it.

Did you grant permissions to your colleague on this site or document library? They will need Contribute or higher permissions to upload a file.

I have created a team in Teams that creates a sharepoint site on the background. The user that cannot upload a file is a owner of the team in teamsite. And i have made a library on the sharepoint site. But the user can not upload files to that library eventhou he is owner in Teams.

Can you check if library is using unique permissions? You can check user permissions on library from Library settings page --> Permissions for this document library option.

You have to grant permissions to your colleague on the SharePoint site (if document library inherits site permissions) OR document library (if document library has unique permissions) so that they can upload documents to library you created.
They will need Contribute or higher permissions to upload files in the SharePoint document library.
Check below Microsoft official documentations for more information:

Share a SharePoint site
Customize permissions for a SharePoint list or library
SharePoint user permissions and permission levels - Permission levels are similar in both SharePoint Online and SharePoint On-Premises.
Determine permission levels and groups in SharePoint


I can upload my file to the library but my collegea not. And we are both team owner. When he upload a file het get status Pending

I think Approval settings are enabled for this library. Do you need those approval settings? If not, you can disable it from Library settings page --> Versioning Settings option --> Set Require content approval for submitted items? to No and click "OK" button at the bottom of settings page to save the changes. Let me know if it works for you.

If your user permissions are fine, additionally check the following points:
1.Please make sure that the filenames are supported by SharePoint. You can check to see if your file name is legit based on this article.
2.Please make sure that the file types you are uploading are supported by SharePoint.
Please go to SharePoint Admin Center->Settings->Sync and check your organization's custom file types that cannot be uploaded. If you are unable to view this, please contact your SharePoint administrator to do so.

